# null pointer exception cannot be fixed

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

i m getting a nullpointer exception continuously but i can't figure out where the problem is.
Please help.
it is a java code for client on android. i m trying to send and receive data simultaneously but it is not working.
   <

```
package com.chat.clientone;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.*;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;


 import android.text.Html;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.util.*;

 public class ClientoneActivity extends Activity {

public static final String SERVER_HOSTNAME = "10.0.2.2";
public static final int SERVER_PORT = 3000;
private TextView tv=null;
private EditText et=null;
private Button bt=null;
private Socket socket;
BufferedReader in=null;
PrintWriter out=null;
String messageOut=null, messageIn=null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);                 
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.clienttext);
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.clientedit);
    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cbtn);


   try {          
           socket = new Socket(SERVER_HOSTNAME, SERVER_PORT);

           tv.append("Connected to server " +
                   SERVER_HOSTNAME + ":" + SERVER_PORT);
           et.append("Enter Username");

        }catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
        }


            try {
                 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                 tv.append("NOTE: Enter 'quit' to end the program.\n");
                 while (true) {
                    //System.out.print("SEND:      ");
                    messageOut = et.getText().toString()+System.getProperty("line.separator");
                   Log.e("LOG_TAG", "ERRRRRRRROOORRR"+messageOut);
                    if (messageOut.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))  {
                          // User wants to quit.  Inform the other side
                          // of the connection, then close the connection.
                       out.println("CLOSE");
                       out.flush();
                    //   connection.close();
                       tv.append("Connection closed.");
                   //    finish();
                       System.exit(0);
                       break;
                    }
                    out.println(messageOut);
                    out.flush();
                    if (out.checkError()) {
                       throw new IOException("Error occurred while transmitting message.");
                    }
                    tv.append("WAITING...");
                    messageIn = in.readLine();
                    if (messageIn.length() > 0) {
                            // The first character of the message is a command. If 
                            // the command is CLOSE, then the connection is closed.  
                            // Otherwise, remove the command character from the 
                            // message and procede.
                       if (messageIn.equalsIgnoreCase("CLOSE")) {
                          tv.append("Connection closed at other end.");
                         // connection.close();
                     //     finish();
                          System.exit(0);
                          break;
                       }

                    }
                    tv.append("RECEIVED:  " + messageIn);
                 }
              }
              catch (Exception e) {
                 tv.append("Sorry, an error has occurred.  Connection lost.");
                 tv.append(e.toString());
                 System.out.println(e);
                 Log.e("LOG_TAG", "ERRRRRRRROOORRR"+e.toString());
                 System.exit(1);
              }


}
```

}

Comment: When you get an exception, please log it with the three-argument log call: `Log.e("LOG_TAG", "ERROR", e);` This will generate a more informative logcat output that includes a stack trace. Then paste the relevant logcat output and point out to us the line in the code that is generating the NPE (since we don't know how to count lines in your source).

Comment: also "System.exit();" should never be in your Android code.

Comment: @AndroidKiller it was a problem with variable "out". it wasnt initialized.

Comment: @L7ColWinters why can't we use System.exit();

Comment: **HOLY COW**... your code atrocious.

Comment: @JoxTraex can you please help instead of criticizing? i m new to android and java

Comment: My suggestion is learn basic OOP then tackle android and it will be easier.

Comment: @JoxTraex can you please elaborate taking the above code as example?

Comment: or can anyone please tell me how to make the client read and write at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize out with BufferWriter.

```
out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
```

Comment: i did that. but it is still not working. it shows only blank screen. no layout.

Comment: Debug the above line and see what is there in `socket`

Answer (score 3):

where have you initialised **out** variable... its **null** so you are getting nullpointerException  at `out.println("CLOSE");`

Comment: @L7ColWinters.. when someone says null pointer exception and has lot many class Variable its most probable that they are not initialized..